# How to implement "less" on derived types without dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading, virtual

I want to implement a "less"-type operation on the following classes:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual int type() const = 0;
  private:
    int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
  public:
    virtual int type() const { return 1; }
  private:
    int d1; 
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
  public:
    virtual int type() const { return 2; }
  private:
    int d2;
};
```

where `o1 < o2` if its type is smaller and if the types are equal then the elements are compared (first b then d1 or d2).

Note that there are other operations (eg. equals) with similar problem structure.

How can I do this without using `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: The base class knows nothing about data members d1 and d2 of the derived classes.

Comment: @hennes Well, I prefer not to override operator <, less is just a typical operation where you have the same problem structure.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `dynamic_cast` nor `type`. For that matter, no public members at all, either.

```
class Base {
  virtual bool less( Base const & rhs ) const {
    return false;
  }

  int b;

  friend bool operator < ( Base const & lhs, Base const & rhs ) {
    std::type_info const & ltype = typeid (lhs);
    std::type_info const & rtype = typeid (rhs);
    if ( ltype == rtype ) {
      if ( lhs.b < rhs.b ) return true;
      if ( rhs.b < lhs.b ) return false;
      return lhs.less( rhs ); // Dynamic types of lhs and rhs already match.
    }
    return ltype.before( rtype );
  }
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
  virtual bool less( Base const & rhs_base ) const {
    // Since rhs_base is known to be of this type, use static_cast.
    Derived1 const & rhs = static_cast< Derived1 const & >( rhs_base );
    return d1 < rhs.d1;
  }

  int d1; 
};

// Same for Derived2
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af1aae28630878f5 (Includes tests)

Comment: Nice and clean solution! The only caveat is that querying typeid and doing a dynamic cast has the same complexity (on some implementation this means comparison of long strings).

Comment: Well, from your solition one can easily optimise out the typeid mess using a get_type() function that's why the +1 from me.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Querying `typeid` has negligible complexity — it just loads a `type_info` pointer from the vtable. `type_info::before` can (and usually does) mean comparing strings, but checking equality is usually accomplished by comparing the `type_info` pointers which is essentially free. On the other hand, the virtual function `type()` requires an indirect call which is quite expensive. `dynamic_cast` can be expensive or not; it doesn't rely on strings but walks through a linked data structure. Anyway, premature optimization is the root of much evil.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this, very interesting! I feel like I learned something new today

Answer (score 1):

The operator can look the following way

```
class Base {
 public:
  virtual int type() const = 0;
  virtual int get_value() const { return b; }
 private:
  int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base{
 public:
  virtual int type() const { return 1; }
  virtual int get_value() const { return d1; }     
 private:
  int d1; 
};

class Derived2 : public Base{
 public:
  virtual int type() const { return 2; }
  virtual int get_value() const { return d2; }     
 private:
  int d2;
};

bool operator <( const Base &lhs, const Base &rhs )
{
    int t1 = lhs.type();
    int t2 = rhs.type();
    int b1 = lhs.Base::get_value();
    int b2 = rhs.Base::get_value();
    int d1 = lhs.get_value();
    int d2 = rhs.get_value();

    return std::tie( t1, b1, d1 ) < std::tie( t2, b2, d2 );  
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program. I added one more derived class that to show that the operator does not depend on the number of the derived classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tuple>

class Base 
{
public:
    Base( int x ) : b( x ) {}        
    virtual int type() const = 0;
    virtual int get_value() const { return b; }

private:
    int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1( int x, int y ) : Base( y ), d1( x ) {}
    virtual int type() const { return 1; }
    virtual int get_value() const { return d1; }     

private:
    int d1; 
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2( int x, int y ) : Base( y ), d2( x ) {}
    virtual int type() const { return 2; }
    virtual int get_value() const { return d2; }     

private:
    int d2;
};

class Derived3 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived3( int x, int y ) : Base( y ), d3( x ) {}
    virtual int type() const { return 2; }
    virtual int get_value() const { return d3; }     

private:
    int d3;
};

bool operator <( const Base &lhs, const Base &rhs )
{
    int t1 = lhs.type();
    int t2 = rhs.type();
    int b1 = lhs.Base::get_value();
    int b2 = rhs.Base::get_value();
    int d1 = lhs.get_value();
    int d2 = rhs.get_value();

    return std::tie( t1, b1, d1 ) < std::tie( t2, b2, d2 );  
}

int main()
{
    Derived1 d11( 1, 2 );
    Derived1 d12( 1, 1 );
    
    std::cout << "d11 < d12 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d11 < d12 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d12 < d11 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d12 < d11 ) << std::endl;
    
    Derived2 d21( 1, 2 );
    
    std::cout << "d21 < d11 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d21 < d11 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d11 < d21 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d11 < d21 ) << std::endl;

    Derived3 d31( 1, 2 );

    std::cout << "d31 < d21 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d31 < d21 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d21 < d31 = " << std::boolalpha <<( d21 < d31 ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
d11 < d12 = false
d12 < d11 = true
d21 < d11 = false
d11 < d21 = true
d31 < d21 = false
d21 < d31 = false
```

Comment: Interesting idea, Vlad, the only problem is that this solution is not extendable.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs Why did you decide that it is not extendable? You can declare other derived classes and the operator will work.

Comment: If you have more data members than one, you need to keep reimplementing the less function.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs I do not understand the sense of this your comment.  Using any approach if you add one more data member that takes part in the operator you have to change either the operator or class definitions.

Comment: Let's assume you need a new variable int d11 in Derived1. Now, you can throw out get_value() as a virtual function. Since in Derived1 you'd need to return a pair. In other solutions you only need to insert an if-else for the new data member into a single function.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs What is the difference between using directly data member or its getter? There is no any sense in your words.

Comment: Can you write your example with Derived1 having an extra data member d11 that should be also compared?

Comment: @Barnabas Did you read your own question? How it is related that you each time change your classes. And with what you are going to compare new data member of class Derived1 in class for example Derived2?

Comment: Yes, I get your confusion and I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough for you. You don't compare d2 to d1 ever, because they mean different things. I'll change the type of d2 to char and then you'll see.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs I understand what you are saying. Simply what you are saying does not have any sense and says about you that you do not understand OOP and nothing more.

Comment: Don't be upsed Vlad you get it right next time. I recommend you to read http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876

Answer (score 0):

You need double dispatch:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int type() const = 0;
    virtual bool greaterWithBase(const Base&) const = 0;
    virtual bool lessWithDerived1(const Derived1&) const = 0;
    virtual bool lessWithDerived2(const Derived2&) const = 0;
private:
    int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    int type() const override { return 1; }
    bool greaterWithBase(const Base& base) const override
    {
        return base.lessWithDerived1(*this);
    }

    bool lessWithDerived1(const Derived1& rhs) const override
    {
        return std::tie(b, d1) < std::tie(rhs.b, rhs.d1);
    }
    bool lessWithDerived2(const Derived2&) const override {return true;}
private:
    int d1;
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    int type() const override { return 1; }
    bool greaterWithBase(const Base& base) const override
    {
        return base.lessWithDerived2(*this);
    }

    bool lessWithDerived1(const Derived1&) const override {return false;}
    bool lessWithDerived2(const Derived2& rhs) const override
    {
        return std::tie(b, d2) < std::tie(rhs.b, rhs.d2);
    }
private:
    int d2;
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but what if I have Derived1,... Derived8?